# scipy.interpolate.splrep: What do the derivatives beyond der=1 represent?

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, calculus

I've been using [`scipy.interpolate.splrep`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) to create path animations in a 3D application. I use the first derivative (`der=1`) option to get the tangent on curve at a given point to calculate a `forward vector` which the allows me to orient the object following that path.

This is when it occurred to me that `splrep` can also compute the second (`der=2`) and third (der=3) derivatives (and presumably more?)

I know that the `first derivative` of a spline at a given query point corresponds to the tangent on spline at that point, what i'd like to know is what do the derivatives beyond (`der > 1`) represent and what can the values `splrep` returns for them be used for?

Comment: This is really a math question rather than a programming question. The second derivative of the function *y = f(x)* is just the derivative of the first derivative with respect to *x* (and so on and so forth for higher derivatives). In this context the second derivative would tell you the rate at which the derivative ("slope") of the curve is increasing or decreasing (imagine drawing a line tangent to the *derivative* of *f(x)*). For example, at a local maximum the derivative would be zero and the second derivative would be negative (since the slope decreases with increasing *x*).

Comment: Thanks for the math refresher!  And you're right as formulated this is more about math than programming. I'll rephrase my question later tonight so it's more about programming. Ultimately what i want i to find a proper way to calculate orthogonal matrices on a spline (so the objects i animate on my path can bank with the spline as it curves). I thought that the second and third derivatives could help me achieve this but there are caveats.